# Display data with the same user_id and sum the amount_unit column

Tags: laravel

**Table**

```
--------------------------------------------------
user_id                           amount_unit
--------------------------------------------------
82ei3j3r2ijwkjewk32893e                3
2y8r42t8f432929420234y8                2
2y8r42t8f432929420234y8                4
82ei3j3r2ijwkjewk32893e                2
--------------------------------------------------
```

**Result**

```
--------------------------------------------------
user_id                           amount_unit
--------------------------------------------------
82ei3j3r2ijwkjewk32893e                5
2y8r42t8f432929420234y8                6
--------------------------------------------------
```

I also want to display `user_id`. I tried on the controller to only display the sum of `amount_unit`,

```php
$data = BankDeposit::with('user')->selectRaw('SUM(amount_unit) as au')
    ->groupBy('user_id')->get();

foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `user_id` to `selectRaw()` too.

```
$data = BankDeposit::with('user')->selectRaw('SUM(amount_unit) as au, user_id')
           ->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```